# Using an op-amp to drive LEDs according to an incoming signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, inverting-amplifier, negative-feedback, virtual-ground

The following schematic was suggested for visualizing the frequency (which is variable) of an oscillator using two LEDs that light up alternatingly. It seems that the value of the resistor determines how much voltage is provided to the LEDs. I've never seen this circuit before and was wondering, is there no need for a current limiting resistor for these LEDs?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ01EK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: An LED sets its own voltage. You vary its brightness by varying its current. In this circuit the voltage feeding the resistor's input produces a current in the resistor and the opamp inverts it and causes the LED current to be the same as in the resistor.

Comment: @Audioguru Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R1 is already the current limiting resistor. Since no current is flowing into the opamp input, and its inverting input is at ground due to the feedback loop, the current through R1 will flow directly into the diodes. Therefore the current flowing through the LEDs will be
$$ I_D = \frac{V_{osc}(t)}{R_1} = \frac {5\ \mathrm{V}} {4.7\ \mathrm{k\Omega}} \sin( \omega t)$$

The current amplitude through the LEDs is approximately 1 mA. In the equation I have assumed sinusoidal oscillation.

It might depend on the LED specification, but I feel the LED current is a little low.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you elaborate how exactly you arrive at this solution? As I understand the op amp tries to make the inverting input go to 0V, so let's say the input is at 5V, then the output of the op amp must be negative. But I don't quite see how we can compute the current through the LED from that?

Comment: Please could you expand on this with explanatory text, for new readers .

Comment: Ah I think now I understand: Since the inverting input is kept at 0V, we can compute the current flowing throu the resistor using Ohms Law, which is \$I = V_{osc} / R_1\$. Since (in the ideal case) there is no current flowing through the inverting input, all the current must go through the LED, therefore the current through the resistor is equal to the current through the LEDs.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the schematic with some helpful labels:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDl5Nw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With negative feedback, an op-amp adjusts its output to equalise the potentials \$V_Q\$ at Q (inverting) and \$V_P\$ at P (non-inverting). In this case, the non-inverting input is grounded (0 V), \$V_P=0\$, and the inverting input is continuously "adjusted" by the op-amp to equal that, so:

$$ V_Q = V_P = 0 $$

There happens to be a couple of LEDs in the feedback path, but that doesn't matter. The op-amp will always find the exact output potential \$V_{OUT}\$ necessary to make \$V_Q = V_P\$, regardless of what's in that path. In this case the output will be different from \$V_Q\$ by an LED's own forward voltage, to achieve \$V_Q = 0\$.

The key to understanding why no current limiting resistor is required here, is to understand what currents are flowing and why. To find out what current \$I_1\$ is flowing in resistor R1, we use Ohm's law. Since we know that the op-amp maintains \$V_Q = 0\ \mathrm{V}\$, current \$I_1\$ is always:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1 &= \frac{V_{R1}}{R_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{IN} - V_Q}{R_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{IN} - 0}{R_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

With \$V_{IN}=+2\ \mathrm{V}\$ as shown, that's:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1 &= \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{+2\ \mathrm{V}}{4.7\ \mathrm{k\Omega}} = 426\ \mathrm{\mu A} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The op-amp's inputs are very, very high resistance, and none of that current enters (or leaves} via that route (notice I've marked the non-inverting input current as zero), which means that *all* of that current passes to/from the output via one or the other LED. Therefore:

$$ I_2 = I_1 = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} $$

If it isn't clear yet, consider that the op-amp's role here can be described like this: the op-amp output sinks or sources exactly the right current through one LED or the other, applying exactly the correct voltage across the LED, to produce the exact condition \$V_Q = V_P = 0\ \mathrm{V}\$, regardless of LED characteristics or behavior.

Since the currents \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ must be equal in this arrangement, \$V_{OUT}\$ automatically settles at whatever value is necessary to achieve not only the voltage equality \$V_Q = V_P = 0\ \mathrm{V}\$, but also the current equality \$I_1 = I_2\$, and it does this without needing to be told anything about the LEDs.

Consequently, LED current is continuously regulated to be:

$$ I_{LED} = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} $$

This relationship is true regardless of the LED's colour, and forward voltage. Technically, you can consider R1 to be the current limiting element, with a role similar to the resistor in a simple series pair resistor+LED, but instead of having a fixed supply voltage across the pair, now the op-amp takes care of applying the exact voltage necessary across the LED to pass \$I_{LED}\$, under control of potential \$V_{IN}\$.

It's like magic. It still amazes me today, even decades after first learning about this. Negative feedback is pure magic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an EE, so if I am wrong please correct me. Even with these equations not being wrong they are a good general "rule of thumb". The voltage required to turn on the led should also be included inside these equations for exactness. Different LEDs have various voltage requirements, so the better equation would be ILED(each color) = ((Vosc-LEDv)/R1). This does not account for any voltage gain circuit.

Comment: The LEDs are current driven. The op-amp compensates automatically for different LED voltage drops due to feedback. Therefore, there is no need to know the LED forward voltage drop in this analysis hence why the LED voltage doesn't appear in the math; the op-amp actively "removes" the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

## Basic idea

The idea on which this particular circuit is based is much more general. It is so universal that it can be seen in non-electric form all around us. We ourselves frequently use this remedy in a variety of situations where we compensate a (negative) quantity with an equivalent opposite (positive) quantity; hence the popular name "compensation". We can figuratively call it ***"removing disturbance through anti-disturbance"***.

So, in this specific circuit solution, the undesired LED forward voltage drop is compensated by adding an equal voltage to it, and we can figuratively call it ***"removing voltage through anti-voltage"***.

In electronics, all inverting op-amp circuits implement it using op-amps and negative feedback, but as I have shown below, this is not absolutely necessary.

## How to explain it

The paradox here is that such a simple, intelligible and universal idea is not easily accepted. The explanation of this phenomenon in circuits is done through orthodox textbook explanations that use trite verbal clichés, and in fact do not explain anything. That is why there are so many questions here in SE EE on this topic.

For this reason, I will try to reveal the philosophy of this phenomenon through several possible implementations of two exemplary devices - an *"ideal" zero-resistance ammeter* and an *"ideal" zero-voltage LED*. My idea is to let the former serve as a prelude to explaining the latter (the OP's LED circuit).

## Making perfect ammeter

Imagine that you need to measure the current in the simplest Ohm's electrical circuit consisting only of a voltage source V and a resistor R.

### "Ideal" ammeter

If you insert an "ideal" zero-resistance ammeter (from the CircuitLab library), there is no voltage drop across it and the current is exactly according to Ohm's law, I = V/R = 10/1 = 10 mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSdc1J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Imperfect ammeter

But if you do not have an "ideal" ammeter handy, and insert a "bad" ammeter with a high (e.g. 1 kΩ) internal resistance RA, the latter adds to the existing R and the current drops dramatically - I = V/(R + RA) = 10/2 = 5 mA. Hint: You can set the ammeter resistance in its "parameters" window by double-clicking the ammeter (R1k means "an imperfect ammeter with internal resistance 1 kΩ").

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJXIvr.png)</sup>

Put another way, a voltage (drop) VA is lost across the ammeter and the current decreases - I = (V - VA)/R = (10 - 5)/1 = 5 mA.

### "Perfect ammeter man"

The remedy is to add the same voltage to the input voltage. For this purpose, we connect another voltage source -VA and adjust its voltage equal to the voltage drop across the ammeter. For convenience, we can connect a null indicator NI between the midpoint and ground, and maintain it with a zero reading (the so-called "virtual ground" VG).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBCICP.png)</sup>

As a result of this "negative feedback game", the total voltage across the network of two elements - the ammeter and the compensating voltage source, is zero... as though it is a "piece of wire"; hence the name "virtual short".

### "Copying" perfect ammeter

To automate this "game", we can make a *behavioral voltage source* -VA copy the ammeter voltage drop. Note that it will do this mechanically without negative feedback.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmoKUJ.png)</sup>

### Perfect ammeter with negative feedback

But the most precise way is by using negative feedback. Above we did this in a slow human way acting like *integrators*. In circuits, we make it with the help of *amplifiers*. So, let's make the source amplify 100,000 times the midpoint voltage. It is all the same, but it happens almost instantly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1DLgb.png)</sup>

### Perfect op-amp ammeter

In practical circuits, an op-amp does this magic fast and precise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f021jV.png)</sup>

### Perfect negative resistance ammeter

With the next experiment I want to show once again that negative feedback is the best but not the only way to implement this idea. Here is an extravagant no-feedback way - through *negative resistance* (there is such a possibility in CircuitLab). For this purpose, we connect a negative resistor with resistance -RA in series to the positive ammeter resistance RA. The result is the same as above - zero resistance and voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh448B.png)</sup>

## Making "perfect LED"

Having seen and studied how the resistance of the simplest possible element - a *linear resistor* - can be neutralized, now we can very easily do the same with a non-linear element - a *diode (LED)*.

### "Ideal" current load

Here it is convenient to combine the resistor R with an ammeter (R1k means "an imperfect ammeter with internal resistance 1 kΩ"). Remember that you can set its resistance in the "parameters" window by double-clicking the ammeter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYcwLS.png)</sup>

### Imperfect LED

For simplicity and clarity, in this conceptual circuit, we can represent the LED as an "ideal" diode D from the CircuitLab library having a forward voltage of 2 V.

**V = 10 V:** The problem is the same as with the resistor R above - a voltage drop VF is lost across the diode and the current decreases - I = (V - VF)/R = (10 - 2)/1 = 8 mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSXKAp.png)</sup>

**V = 1 V:** This becomes even more of a problem when the input voltage is less than the LED voltage; then the current even stops flowing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKpNI4.png)</sup>

### "Perfect LED man"

But we solve the problem by applying the "clever trick" from above - connecting an additional voltage source and setting its voltage equal to the LED voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f83KEC.png)</sup>

### "Copying perfect LED"

Then we can automate this "negative feedback game" by the help of a *behavioral voltage source* -VA that copies the LED voltage drop. Remember that it does this mechanically without negative feedback.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ4Bwz.png)</sup>

### "Perfect LED" with negative feedback

Then we make the source amplify 100,000 times the midpoint voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwy4yb.png)</sup>

### "Perfect LED" with various VF

Finally, we make an op-amp does this magic thus obtaining a 1/2 of the OP's circuit. Let's see how the op-amp reacts at two different values of the LED voltage.

**VF = 1 V:** The op-amp adjusts its output voltage equal to -1 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBAJCY.png)</sup>

**VF = 3 V:** The op-amp adjusts its output voltage equal to -3 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMhaQB.png)</sup>

### "Perfect battery LED"

Finally, I want to show for the last time that this trick can also be implemented (with less success) without feedback. Since the voltage drop of the LED is almost constant, it can be compensated with a constant voltage source (e.g. a battery) having the same voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmwOnC.png)</sup>

## Conclusions

- In life, we compensate for losses with gains of equal value.
- In circuits, we compensate voltage drops with voltages of equal value.
- For this purpose, we connect a following voltage source (op-amp) in series to the passive element (LED).
- Thus the imperfect passive element is "helped" by the additional voltage source.
- The combination of a passive element and following voltage source can be considered as an "ideal current load" with zero total resistance (voltage).
- So it can be driven by a very low input voltage starting from zero even if VF is very high.